# Function loop for creating and saving advanced statistical barplot (gglot) with dependence of response variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I would like to create and save advanced statistical barplot with help of loop function. I would like to change response variable for statistical analyses (using loop), names of y axis and maximum limit for y axis. I have tried these, but I got error message.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(agricolae)
library(dplyr)

dat <- mtcars
dat$cyl <- factor(dat$cyl)
attach(dat)

selected_dat <- dat[,c(1,3:7)]
selected_names <- names(selected_dat)
ylab_names <- c(expression("MPG (unit "[A]* ")"), expression("disp (unit "[B]* ")"), expression("hp (unit "[C]* ")"),  
                expression("drat (unit "[D]* ")"), expression("wt (unit "[E]* ")"), expression("qsec (unit "[F]* ")"))

for (i in selected_names) {
   for (j in ylab_names) {

model_1 <- lm(paste0(i)~cyl, data=dat)
out <- HSD.test(model_1, "cyl", group = T)
out_names <- out$groups
out_names <- tibble::rownames_to_column(out_names, "cyl")
ordered_outnames <- out_names[match(levels(dat$cyl), out_names$cyl),]
new_data <- data.frame(lapply(ordered_outnames, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
statistics_letter <- new_data$groups

ylimit_max <- c(mean(paste0(i)) + sd(paste0(i)) + sd(paste0(i)))

df <- dat %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(
    n=n(),
    mean = round(mean(paste0(i), na.rm = T),2),
    sd = sd(paste0(i), na.rm = T))

rplot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = cyl,  y = mean,  fill=cyl)) +
  ylab(paste0("j")) +
  xlab("cyl") +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", lwd=1.25, width=0.6) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd),width=.2, lwd=0.5,col="black", na.rm = T) +
  stat_summary(aes(label=stat(y)), fun.y=mean, geom="text", colour="darkblue", size=5, position=position_dodge(0.85), vjust = 8) +
  geom_text(aes(label = statistics_letter, y=mean+sd), position = position_dodge(0.85), color="black", size=6, vjust = -2) +
  geom_text(aes(y = max(mean)/10, label = paste0("n = ", n)), position = position_dodge(0.85), size=5, colour="darkred") +  
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, ylimit_max)) 
ggsave(rplot, file=paste0(i, ".png"), width = 10, height = 8.5, units = "in")

    }
  }
```

I would like to get this type of barplot separately for these response variables: mpg, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec (total of 6 graphs).

[image]

I would like create and save total of 6 barplot at once, but when I tried to use loop function I got error message. How can I fix this error? Can somebody help me? Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few errors in your code - they all are related to your use of `i` and `j`.

First, write your `lm` formula as a string, then convert it to a formula. This is safer and less error-prone than trying to paste together in your call to `lm()`:

```
frml <- as.formula(paste(i, "~ cyl")) # if `cyl` can be variable, paste the var name
model_1 <- lm(frml, data=dat)
```

Next, `i` and `j` are strings of column names in `dat`, not vectors. So when you call a summary function like `mean(paste0(i))`, you aren't getting the mean of that column vector. You can fix this by calling the actual column in `dat`, like this:

```
ylimit_max <- c(mean(dat[[i]]) + sd(dat[[i]]) + sd(dat[[i]]))
```

There are a few other places in your code where this occurs - make sure to update each one.

Finally, I would recommend using `ylab({{j}})` in your ggplot syntax.

After these updates, you will find your plots are produced without error, e.g.:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for Your help, but this plot contains several mistakes. In this case the mean for qsec variable is 19.1 (cyl 4), 18.0 cyl 6) and 16.8 (cyl 8). The same mistakes are on errobars: sd for qsec is 1.68 (cyl 4), 1.71 (cyl 6) and 1.20 (cyl 8). Besides, syntax ylab({{j}}) is not working. Could you please check these code again and fix these errors?

Comment: Your code may have additional errors - I did not check to see if your values were accurate. You asked for help with the error you were getting - this code resolves the main issue with your syntax.

Comment: Mean (and SD) values are wrong because the program does not calculate properly when I use the loop function (it is ok when I create these graphs separately for each response variable). Therefore these values are wrong in your graphs too.